# Произведение и сумма элементов матрицы без циклов

Tags: математика, matlab

[image: Матрица] [image: Нужно найти]

Необходимо решить эту задачу без использования циклов. Я никак не могу понять, как это сделать правильно. Если я правильно всё понял, то вот решение на C# (в Matlab'е не силён):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] array = new int[,] { {  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2 },
                                        {  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2 },
                                        {  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2 },
                                        { -1, -1, -1,  4,  0,  0 },
                                        { -1, -1, -1,  0,  4,  0 },
                                        { -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  4 } };

            double multiplication = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                double sum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    sum += Math.Pow(array[i, j], array[i, j]);
                }
                multiplication *= sum;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(multiplication);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Получилось *55,962,140,625*.

Вот матрица для Matlab:

```
G10P1 = ones(3);
G10 = [ G10P1, G10P1 * 2; G10P1 * -1, eye(3) * 4 ];
```

У меня только это получилось и то, не уверен, что делаю в том направлении:

```
ij = 1:6;
p = sum(G10(ij, ij).^G10(ij, ij))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ij = 1:6;
> p = sum(G10(ij, ij).^G10(ij, ij))
> ```

Во-первых, для возведение элементов матрицы в собственною степень срез тут абсолютно бесполезен, можно просто написать: `G10.^G10`. Если бы функция была посложнее, то можно было бы воспользоваться [`arrayfun(@(x) x^x, G10)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html).

По умолчанию [`sum()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) суммирует матрицу по столбцам, поэтому надо воспользоваться его второй формой и передать размерность: `sum(G10.^G10, 2)`

Для перемножения элементов вектора есть функция [`prod()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html).

В итоге получается окончательный вариант:

```
prod(sum(G10.^G10, 2))
```

ЗЫ: с чисто математической точки зрения 0<sup>0</sup> — не совсем корректное выражение.